# Blackberry app is very slow on startup, how can i fix this?

Tags: blackberry, startup, image-resizing, performance

I recently updated my app to work on nearly all of the phones. I did this by having the first screen detect the screen size and then change all the images (there are a lot of images). As such, the startup on the non-base model phones is like 15 seconds, it looks like the phone is freezing but its just changing the images. It does this every time I open the app. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: You should post the code with the image changing algorithm to detect the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Make sure that you are resizing images on a separate thread (no UI Blocking operation).
- It would be better if you store all the resized images on persistent
  storage so that you don't need to resize same image twice on a
  handset.

[edited]

Some links about how to use persistence storage:

- [BlackBerry persistent store](https://web.archive.org/web/20120923195126/http://www.riccomini.name:80/Topics/Mobile/BlackBerry/BlackBerryPersistentStore/)
- [Create a persistent data store](https://web.archive.org/web/20130623062312/http://docs.blackberry.com:80/en/developers/deliverables/11938/Create_a_persistent_data_store1_510371_11.jsp)
- [BlackBerry Java Application Development Guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20111124232244/http://docs.blackberry.com:80/en/developers/deliverables/11940/BlackBerry_Java_Application-Development_Guide--790641-1109120224-001-5.0_Beta-US.pdf)

Sample Code Snippet for making a Bitmap object persistable:

```java
class PersistableBitmap implements Persistable {
    int width;
    int height;
    int[] argbData;
    
    public PersistableBitmap(Bitmap image) {
        width = image.getWidth();
        height = image.getHeight();
        argbData = new int[width * height];
        image.getARGB(argbData, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmapImage() {
        Bitmap image = new Bitmap(width, height);
        image.setARGB(argbData, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
        return image;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about using persistent storage. But I don't know how I would do that. I am semi familiar with pers stor but how would I save a modified image file?

Comment: You can try the links posted on answer section, and also you can check the class `PersistableBitmap` which can be used as a persistable Bitmap object.